# (efficiently) Writing Identical Data to Multiple Files in C

Tags: c, multithreading, file, io

I am presented with a situation where I must write some string into multiple files. An immediate solution would be to simply loop through each file, writing the same data to each separately. If one wanted to write identical data to multiple file streams concurrently, how would they achieve this efficiently? Though this situation is hypothetical, an example case may be - if one wanted to write to both a `FILE*` and the `stdout` stream:

```
FILE* streams[] = { /* some file streams */ };

/* is there a more efficient or elegant approach? */
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(streams); i++) 
    fputs(/* data */, streams[i]);
```

Though this example shows writing to only 2 target streams, a potential solution should enable writing to as many as 8 file streams. In order to achieve this, is it possible to link files so they point to the same location? In the case that there is no practical method for mirroring file writes, if it is possible to offload file write operations onto a different thread, please don't refrain from posting.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Files in file systems usually do not share "common blocks" - as underneath the file stream, disks still work block oriented. As such, unless you invent a new file system, there is no shortcut to write once and link the block to many files, I think. Writing with multiple threads to the same disk is also not prone to help you much, because the writes will be serialized (mutexed) most likely. Multiple threads might earn you something, maybe but I consider it unlikely.

Comment: Why don't you write to a file once and copy the file using your filesystem and operating systems. I am sure they will written in the most optimized way.

Comment: You need to trial either multiple threads or asynchronous writes.  In general, having multiple IO requests outstanding on spinners, (the hard disk driver can optimize head moves), multiple drives and/or networked drives will improve overall performance.  Really, you have to try it:)

Comment: time stamp all methods and see which one is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

> If one wanted to write identical data to multiple file streams concurrently, how would they achieve this efficiently?

I guess loop is the only option.

> In order to achieve this, is it possible to link files so they point to the same location?

If your N files need to be identical, sure you can write just to one and make hard links to this file. Note though that not all the file systems support hard links and any change to one of the files will change all the files at one, because it is basically the same file:

```
ln orig_file copy1
```

> it is possible to offload file write operations onto a different thread

Sure, threads will help to improve the performance, but your few lines program will become a much longer. Try to increase underneath buffers instead:

```
man setvbuf
```

Comment: If I were to wrap that logic into a function, then instead of putting the data into the stream directly - pushing it onto a queue(array) of char buffers.Then dedicate a thread to constantly writing the top most buffer into its target file(s).Would this be more efficient in any way? Keep in mind, I am somewhat uneducated on multithreading.

Comment: It depends. You can juice more performance out of your application until you quite sure the bottleneck is your application. But in fact your old HDD might be the real issue here. So if you up to learning multi-threading just for fun - go for it. If you expect the performance will double on two threads - no, most probably it will not. Monitor your disk load to make a reasonable decision. Look at asynchronous I/O (man aio) as suggested in the comments. Or do nothing and have a simple and robust application with reasonable performance...